# How for Android to load / read local Realm file?

Tags: android, assets, realm

I have a Test.realm file inside the asset folder. But I don't know how to load the Realm file inside an activity. I have tried this

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .name("Test.realm").build();
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
RealmResults<RealmTestClass0> results = realm.where(RealmTestClass0.class)
                .findAll();
```

But it was crashing on setting config line (second line). From the log it says

`Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must be provided`

So how is the right way to load Realm file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Realm.getInstance()` is correct method for getting Realm's instance.

It looks that you change some of your Realm objects or add new one. Realm detected it and tells that you have new data schema and have to migrate (`RealmMigrationNeededException`).

If you are only developing now - delete application and install it again. It should start to work fine. If your application is in production - you should write some migration code (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations)

Comment: Im using `Realm.getInstance()` on the second line with `config`.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. And it is correct. Your problem is in schema change.

Comment: I tried to delete, and rerun, and it is not crashing at all. thanks for the tip. but the data from database is not yet loaded fom Test.realm file, which i located in assets folder.